# Building a Yocto image IMX8

Tags: ubuntu, yocto, repo

I'm trying to follow a SolidRun tutorial about Yocto image from here (https://github.com/SolidRun/meta-solidrun-arm-imx8).

My command sequence is the following:

First place, I install essentials:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y bc build-essential chrpath cpio diffstat gawk git texinfo wget gdisk 
python3 python3-pip
sudo apt install python-is-python3
sudo apt install python2
```

I install repo manually on the directory yocto (where i want to build the image) and use repo:

```
mkdir yocto
cd yocto    
mkdir -p ~/.bin
PATH="${HOME}/.bin:${PATH}"
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/.bin/repo
chmod a+rx ~/.bin/repo

repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-zeus -m 
imx-5.4.70-2.3.0.xml
repo sync
```

Then I download as they do in their tutorial, and make the other steps:

```
cd sources
git clone https://github.com/SolidRun/meta-solidrun-arm-imx8.git --branch zeus-imx8mp
cd ..
DISTRO=fsl-imx-xwayland MACHINE=imx8mpsolidrun source imx-setup-release.sh -b build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun
```

I add this line *BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-solidrun-arm-imx8"* into conf/bblayers.conf.

Then:

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
```

But I receive a lot of errors like this:

> ERROR: rpm-native-1_4.14.2.1-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch
> command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; unset _PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME;
> export
> PATH="/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/scripts/native-intercept:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native:/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/scripts:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/hosttools";
> export HOME="/home/holoh"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone
> --bare --mirror git://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm /home/holoh/yocto/downloads//git2/github.com.rpm-software-management.rpm
> --progress failed with exit code 128, output: Cloning into bare repository
> '/home/holoh/yocto/downloads//git2/github.com.rpm-software-management.rpm'...
> fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]:
> errno=Connection timed out
>
> ERROR: rpm-native-1_4.14.2.1-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL:
> 'git://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm;branch=rpm-4.14.x'.
> Unable to fetch URL from any source. ERROR: Logfile of failure stored
> in:
> /home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/rpm-native/1_4.14.2.1-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.2200
> ERROR: Task
> (virtual:native:/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/rpm/rpm_4.14.2.1.bb:do_fetch)
> failed with exit code '1' ERROR: jailhouse-0.12-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher
> failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; unset
> _PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME; export PATH="/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native:/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/scripts:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/hosttools";
> export HOME="/home/holoh"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone
> --bare --mirror ssh://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-jailhouse.git
> /home/holoh/yocto/downloads//git2/source.codeaurora.org.external.imx.imx-jailhouse.git
> --progress failed with exit code 128, output: Cloning into bare repository
> '/home/holoh/yocto/downloads//git2/source.codeaurora.org.external.imx.imx-jailhouse.git'...
> ssh: connect to host source.codeaurora.org port 22: Connection timed
> out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.
>
> ERROR: jailhouse-0.12-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL:
> 'git://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-jailhouse.git;protocol=ssh;branch=imx_5.4.70_2.3.0'.
> Unable to fetch URL from any source. ERROR: Logfile of failure stored
> in:
> /home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/imx8mpsolidrun-poky-linux/jailhouse/0.12-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.27149
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/holoh/yocto/sources/meta-imx/meta-sdk/recipes-extended/jailhouse/jailhouse_0.12.bb:do_fetch)
> failed with exit code '1' ERROR: systemd-1_243.2-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher
> failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; unset
> _PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME; export PATH="/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/perl-native:/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/scripts:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/hosttools";
> export HOME="/home/holoh"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone
> --bare --mirror git://github.com/systemd/systemd-stable.git /home/holoh/yocto/downloads//git2/github.com.systemd.systemd-stable.git
> --progress failed with exit code 128, output: Cloning into bare repository
> '/home/holoh/yocto/downloads//git2/github.com.systemd.systemd-stable.git'...
> fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]:
> errno=Connection timed out
>
> ERROR: systemd-1_243.2-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL:
> 'git://github.com/systemd/systemd-stable.git;protocol=git;branch=v243-stable'.
> Unable to fetch URL from any source. ERROR: Logfile of failure stored
> in:
> /home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/systemd/1_243.2-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.22584
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/holoh/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_243.2.bb:do_fetch)
> failed with exit code '1'

It is like there would be some repository problems, but I have tried changed the repo with this:

```
repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-zeus -m 
imx-5.4.70-2.3.8.xml
```

But it is the same.  The tutorial doesn't give more information about the build. What is the problem?

I'm using WSL on Windows, Ubuntu 20.04.

EDIT:I was using that Kernel version because I was following the tutorial on the solidrun github tutorial. Now I'm trying in Ubuntu 22.04 for this kernel and layer version:

```
repo init -u source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-hardknott -m imx-5.10.72-2.2.0.xml
```

But now, i get a new error:

ERROR: m4-native-1.4.18-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed ERROR: m4-native-1.4.18-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/run.do_compile.10148' failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yocto is trying to down clone the git repositories, but that is not working.
The question is why would that fail.

> ```
> Connection timed out
> ```

But your recipe is actually trying to clone (via ssh) from `git://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-jailhouse.git`

Someone has the exact same issue as you

https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/report-bsp-imx-4-19-35-1-1-0-bug-fetch-jailhouse-failed/m-p/1002652

```
git diff
diff --git a/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-extended/jailhouse/jailhouse_0.10.bb b/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-extended/jailhouse/jailhouse_0.10.bb
index 2079718dc..fb4e376ec 100644
--- a/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-extended/jailhouse/jailhouse_0.10.bb
+++ b/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-extended/jailhouse/jailhouse_0.10.bb
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 require jailhouse.inc
 
-SRCBRANCH = "imx_v0.10_y"
-IMX_JAILHOUSE_SRC ?= "git://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-jailhouse.git;protocol=ssh"
+SRCBRANCH = "imx_4.19.35_1.1.0"
+IMX_JAILHOUSE_SRC ?= "git://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-jailhouse.git;protocol=https"
```

So the obvious solution is to change the `protocol=ssh` to `protocol=https` but that is only the start of your problem. There are two real questions you should be asking.

- Question one, this issue was fixed in 2019 (allegedly), why do you not have the lasted version of this layer/recipe.
- Question two, you are building a 4.19 Linux kerel, in 2022. 4.19 is was released on, October 2018, so it is okay. But I would recommend a 5 kernel for all new work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was using that Kernel version because I was following the tutorial on the solidrun github tutorial. Now  I'm trying in Ubuntu 22.04 for this kernel and layer version:  

repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-hardknott -m imx-5.10.72-2.2.0.xml

But now,a new error:

ERROR: m4-native-1.4.18-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: m4-native-1.4.18-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/holoh/yocto/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/run.do_compile.10148' failed with exit code 1

Comment: Solved, making this with hardknott and 5.X.X kernel works fine. Thank you so much.